# Hypothesis Space for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I have the following question on a problem set:

> Considering only linear combinations of monomials $x^k$ for
>   $k=0,...,K$, describe a good hypothesis space to approximate a
>   continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $(-1,1)$ under each of the
>   following constraints:
>
> a. No constraints: $f(x)$ is arbitrary
>
> b. $f$ is even: $f(-x) = f(x)$
>
> c. $f$ is odd: $f(-x) = -f(x)$
>
> d. $f(-1) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$
>
> e. $f(0) = 1$

I know that we want the hypothesis space to: 1) be reasonably small and 2) contain the true hypothesis in order to ensure convergence. So, for part (b) I assume we want the hypothesis space to consist of even monomials (i.e., $x^2,x^4,...$), while for part (c) I assume we want odd monomials (i.e., $x^3,x^5,...$). I'm not sure about the others though. How should we think about those?

Comment: Hint: pay attention to the role of $K$ in the question.

Comment: So, a linear combination of monomials is a polynomial; `K` is the degree of the polynomial and `K` functions as a ceiling on both the number of possible solutions to the polynomial and the number of times its graph crosses the x-axis. In a machine learning context, I know that the degree of the polynomial is important due to the bias/variance tradeoff associated with increasing complexity (increasing `K`).

Comment: That's basically right, but note that $K$ is only an upper bound on the degree of the polynomial.  As far as answering the question goes, one can only guess what is intended; but as an example, I would suppose the answer to $b$ would be the space generated by the monomial functions $x^{2i}$ for $0 \le i \le K/2.$

Comment: I see, thank you. For e, is it permissible to construct a hypothesis space as the set of monomials $x^{1/x}$, which would yield $f(0) = 1$ ?

Comment: "$x^{1/x}$" is not a monomial.  The answer to (e) is the *affine* subspace formed by the constant function $1$ plus the vector subspace generated by the monomials $x^i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, K.$  Unlike the answers to (a) through (d), this "hypothesis space" is not a vector space.